# UI Grid - Editable Cell Template of type 'password' - reveals text when losing focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a requirement to have a password type 'input' as one of my editable cell templates.

When the cell is in focus, I cannot see the text and it is obscured just the way passwords has to be. The problem I am facing is, when it loses its focus, the text/string is revealed.

Here is the plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/m0T1JfhLvDHOGaX9LF51?p=preview. Any help is much appreciated.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'name',
        editableCellTemplate: '<input type = "password" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.uid" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"/>'
        }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
        grid = gridApi.grid;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not making same as from your code as it is uncompleted, You can take guideline from it (You can test it here.) :

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
          $scope.models = [
                {name:"Bob",age:25, city:"NewYork"},              
        ];
    }
```

```css
td > span, th>span {
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
}
th > span {
    background-color:#eee;
}
table td, table th {
    border:1px solid grey;
    }
table {
    width:100%;
}

#main {
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0rc9/angular-1.0.0rc9.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main" ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <table cellpadding="20">
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="(head, value) in models[0]"><span>{{head}}</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in models">
            <td ng-repeat="(name, value) in row" ng-scope>
                <span ng-click="editing = true" ng-hide="editing" ng-bind="row[name]"></span>
                <input ng-model="row[name]" ng-show="editing" />
                <button ng-click="editing = false" ng-show="editing">ok</button>
            </td>    
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see you have used native HTML and angular on this. But my problem is when I use ui-grid as shown in the plnkr. Just for the sake of an example, I took a simpler snippet and what I am doing cannot be achieved without the ui-grid (Wel, it can be but with lot of overheads).

Comment: None of these are type password like requested

Answer (score 0):

Because your cell Template shows the text, so when it loses focus, it goes back to Cell Template showing text.

If that is not correct, please update the plunker to show password even in cell template.

Other thing you can do is always show asterisks in cells.

Here Put cell template as

```
cellTemplate: '<span>******</span>'
```

And then add callback for afterCellEdit

```
 gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope,function(rowEntity, colDef,newValue,oldValue){

    if(newValue != oldValue){
      // Do something.......
      // colDef.field has the name of the column that you are editing

    }

  });
```

Here is this Updated Plunker from yours: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8RSuH9k5ehs6ylaoQ4zp?p=preview)

Comment: The Plunker has errors, it only displays empty ui-grid